# Microsoft Graph API: Cancel recurring events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am currently try to use the Microsoft Graph API to cancel a set of recurring meetings using the following call:

POST `/users/{prinicipalName}/calendar/events/{id}/cancel`

And I am getting back Unsupported segment type error.

I can delete events one at a time, but I need a way to cancel all events in a recurrence. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `/cancel` endpoint.

If you want to remove recurrences from a meeting, you need to set the recurrence pattern to `null`:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/events/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "recurrence": null,
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, looks like it didn't work. I was able accomplish what I needed by using the seriesMasterId and setting thats recurrence to null. Thanks.

Comment: My assumption was that you _were_ using the series master. Instances wouldn't have a recurrence since they're the _result_ of the recurrence pattern.

Comment: Ah, sorry I should've been more descriptive