# Microsft Graph SDK: How to remove recurrence settings from an event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using ASP.Net Core 3.1 and Microsoft Graph Beta 0.15. How can i delete the recurrence settings of an event.

I tried by setting the `Recurrence` property to null but it has no effect.

```
Event graph = new Event();
...
event.Recurrence = null;
await graphServiceClient.Me.Events[id].Request().UpdateAsync(event);
```

This is possible by executing a PATCH request through the Microsoft Graph Explorer as mentioned in
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578497/microsoft-graph-api-cancel-recurring-events)

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/events/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "recurrence": null,
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the SDK today as documented [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/264). The workaround is to build the request and execute it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Try using AdditionalData property

```
var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
additionalData.Add("recurrence", null); 
event.AdditionalData = additionalData;
```